# how to enter a zero character in gvim

Tags: vim

The GVIM wiki indicates that [special characters](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters) can be entered.
Is there any way to insert a null character `\0` in gvim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^V^@` (Ctrl+V, Ctrl+Shift+2 on US keyboards) should do it, or, as the linked article suggests:

- `^V000`
- `^Vo000`
- `^Vx00`
- `^Vu0000`
- `^VU00000000`

Answer (score 0):

Note that vim's ^V is not the same thing as the ^V(LNEXT) in termios.